# What is $\tau$ and $\sigma$ in a geodesic $ψ(x) = (\tau(x),\sigma(x))$?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, space-expansion, cosmological-inflation, geodesics

I'm trying to replicate the results of [this paper](http://aleph.se/papers/Spamming%20the%20universe.pdf) (*Eternity in 6 hours*, written by Stuart Armstrong and Anders Sandberg). On pages 14-15, it discusses the path of an intergalactic probe that is launched from the solar system at a speed $v = pc$ and doesn't receive any acceleration beyond that.

To do this, the authors define a geodesic $\psi(x) = (\tau(x), \sigma(x))$ that obeys the equations

$$
\tau''(x) + a'a(\sigma'(x))^2 = 0 \\
\sigma''(x) + 2 \frac{a'}{a}\sigma'(x)\tau'(x) = 0 \\
a^2(\sigma'(x))^2 - (\tau'(x))^2 = C
$$
where $a$ is the expansion parameter $a(t)$ taken to be 1 today, and $C = p^2 - 1$ is a constant ($p$ is the fraction of the speed of light that the probe was launched at, as defined above).

What does $\tau(x)$ and $\sigma(x)$ mean? I'm pretty sure that $\tau$ denotes time and $\sigma$ denotes distance, and I think that $\sigma$ is in comoving coordinates, but I don't know whether $\tau$ describes local time since the big bang at the place where the probe presently is, or conformal time, or something else entirely. I'm also not sure whether $x$ has any meaning attached to it, or if it's just an arbitrary variable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I emailed the author about it. $\sigma(x)$ is indeed in comoving coordinates, and $\tau(x)$ measures time since the Big Bang (wherever the probe happens to be).

Answer (score 1):

Comparing the geodesic equations $\dfrac{d^2\psi^i}{d\lambda^2}+\Gamma^i_{jk}\dfrac{d\psi^j}{d\lambda}\dfrac{d\psi^k}{d\lambda}=0$ to what the author wrote it appears that $\chi$, defined as

> ...a flat coordinate field in the comoving coordinate frame...

and $\sigma$, the second component of $\psi$, are used interchangeably as $$\Gamma^t_{\chi\chi}=a'(t)a(t),\\ \Gamma^\chi_{t\chi}=\frac{a'(t)}{a(t)}$$

The author uses $x$ as the parameter.

I find it rather confusing that $a$ is a function of $t$ yet $\tau$ is written in the geodesic equation when it is $t$ written in the Christoffel symbols. I do not know of an interpretation/explanation nor why the author chose to do that.